(Still) Stuck on an integral of the form: $\mathcal P \int_0^\infty \frac{x \tanh x}{a^2-x^2} \mathrm dx$
I'm starting my masters in theoretical condensed matter physics soon, and I encountered this integral in a paper I have to read before starting my research.
The paper presented the answer as:
\begin{align}
& \mathcal P \frac1\pi {\LARGE \int}_0^\infty \frac{\omega' \tanh \left(\dfrac{\hbar\omega'}{2k_BT}\right)}{\omega^2-\omega'^2} \mathrm d\omega'
\\[2mm] = & \ \mathrm{Re}\Psi \left(\frac12+\frac{\hbar\omega}{2\pi ik_BT}\right)- \ln\left(\frac{\hbar\omega}{k_BT}\right)
\end{align}
(I left the exact constants to hopefully make the question clearer, but for simplicity, $a\equiv\dfrac{\hbar\omega}{2k_BT}$ in the title).
I found *this thread about a similar enough integral to get the portion with the Digamma function, but it leaves me with a different $\ln$ term.
*Edited to fix wrong link address
UPDATE
So I've tried a couple different approaches:

J.G.'s tip towards the Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem led me to an expression missing the argument inside the Digamma function.
Integrating by parts led me to the following expression:
$$-\frac{1}{2}{\LARGE[}\ln(a^2-x^2)\tanh(x)\Big|_{x=0}^\infty-\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(a^2-x^2)}{\cosh^2(x)}\mathrm{d}x{\LARGE]}$$
The integral on the right gives (using Syvatoslav's method linked above): $\frac{\ln\pi}{2}+\mathrm{Re}\Psi(\frac12+\frac{a}{i\pi})$

So my two remaining problems are:

As Syvatoslav (hey! totally glossed over you commenting) pointed out below, the left term diverges. However, the paper this calculation is from doesn't really mention why and how to treat it. There's just a term of the form $-\ln(2a)$.
The term $\frac{\ln\pi}{2}$ isn't in the final expression given at all.

I don't know if these problems are can be solved mathematically or only physically from the system's properties, if the latter than I'll ask a new question in the physics forum.

Integrating $1/(a^2-x^2)$ will give you $\tanh ^{-1} (x)$. That seems like a good line of thought to pursue

@RC_23 And then represent the $tanh^{-1}(x)$ with $ln$ and then $ln\Gamma$ like in one of the comments on the thread I linked?

Does this help?

@J.G. A few of the integrals look similar but with different powers of $x$ and/or exponents only in the numerator.. I can't figure out how to apply the theorem to my case

At $x\to\infty ,,\frac{x\tanh x}{a^2-x^2}\to -\frac1x$, and the integral diverges as $\sim-\ln x$

Did you use $2x/(a^2-x^2)=1/(a-x)-1/(a+x)$?

@J.G. omg no it totally slipped my mind. I'll try!

@J.G. does it matter that I'm looking for the principal value though? I mean because the real version of the formula has $\int \frac{f(x)}{x\pm i\epsilon}dx = \mathcal P \int \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$, but I'm essentialy looking for the PV of the LHS
Unless you meant the complex version and then I just don't know what the resulting function is

https://xkcd.com/2117/
